# 'UICollectionViewCell' does not have a member named 'image' [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm setting up a project with a `UICollectionView` that displays an image with a label. I created the `ViewController` and the `CellViewController`, just like its supposed to.

In the `CellViewController` the code is the following:

```
class CellController: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!


}
```

But in the `ViewController` when I'm setting up the image it gives me the error. Here's the code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell: UICollectionViewCell = collection.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellController

    cell.image.image = UIImage(named: "star")

    return cell
}
```

And the weirdest thing is, I have a project downloaded from GitHub that is essentially the same as mine, and it works fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the `:UICollectionViewCell`. Although you cast your cell as `CellController` this makes the type `UICollectionViewCell`, which does not have an image property. Removing this or replacing it with `CellController` will fix your problem.

```
let cell = collection.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellController
```

I would also consider renaming your image view to `imageView`. There's something about the line `cell.image.image` that doesn't look right!